# Bluemix Jersey 1.8 415 media error

Tags: jersey, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

In using bleumix liberty with jax-rs1.1 ( inclusive jersey 1.8)
But I get 415 errors media not supported when I use it.

It works on tomcat, but bluemix liberty gives an error.

Any thoughts

Regards
Marc

Comment: Can you post more of the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Liberty jax-rs 1.1 based on Apache Wink, not Jersey. Is your jax-rs implementation using wink? Verify you are providing a wink implementation. Also, remove all the wink jars from your war to avoid conflicts and use what's provided by Liberty. You can either remove them manually from the war `WEB-INF/lib`, or change your `pom.xml` and add `<scope>provided</scope>` for the wink dependencies so that they are not packaged with the war. If you want to use Jersey instead, you will have to disable jax-rs 1.1 by [providing a customized server.xml feature set](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications).

The [Liberty for Java](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/store/cloudOEPaneId=store&orgGuid=06032478-ab0d-4ea7-8193-3b20f82c2ccc&spaceGuid=91d8007d-78c5-4d70-8a4c-d41b90673328&appTemplateGuid=javaHelloWorld&fromCatalog=true) starter application shows a basic implementation example in `src/com/ibm/cloudoe/samples/HelloResource`

Comment: If the use of Jersey is desired instead of using Liberty's built-in jax-rs support, you can still push a WAR but specify the below environment variables to override default feature set: JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY = 'app_archive: {features: [el-3.0, jsp-2.3, servlet-3.1]}'